# How to add libevent to my OSX XCode project?

Tags: xcode, macos, compilation, linker, libevent

I'm trying to add libevent to my OSX XCode Project.
One of my C++ files has the following.

```
#include <evhttp.h>
```

In my /usr/local/lib I have lots of libevent files such as libevent.a and libevent.dylib and so on.

I think, I am supposed to add the libevent.a file to the linked frameworks and libraries, but what about the header files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header files just have to be in your search path. If they're in `/usr/local/include` then make sure that's in the list of places to check. Your project should have things like `/usr/include` by default.